# How to hide div of another webpage when loading that webpage within the div of a main page?

Tags: jquery, html

So i have a main webpage which contains 3 links of other 3 webpages i created. When i click on for example link to PAGE 1, it loads the PAGE 1 within a div with id="article" on my main page.
Now on my main webpage i assigned a toggle function to the div article and on the very page i used jquery to hide the article on load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$("#article").hide();

});

</script>
```

On Pages 1,2 and 3 there is just another div with id article as well and no script or css. So the logic is when i click on Page 1 link it loads the content within the div article there in the div article of this main page. The problem is since the on load function is for the whole window, the div is not hidden when i click on the Page 1 link as only part of the main page has been loaded. Is there a way to hide it when i click on page 1?

Comment: The webpages you are showing up inside the #article are they in an iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you.

$('#article').find('#article').hide();

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
   $("#article").css("display", "none");
});

</script>
```